# File not found in APV PDF Viewer in android.

Tags: android, java-native-interface, pdf-viewer

I m trying to re construct the .so file of APV PDF Viewer in cygwin but it display error of not found

```
#include "fitz.h"
#include "mupdf.h"
```

https://code.google.com/p/apv/source/browse/pdfview/jni/pdfview2/pdfview2.h

In this files r not in project.When I remove it , it displayed so many errors.

Comment: plz tel me the Reason for -1 i hope i can edit my question

Answer (score 1):

I did not give you the -1 but your question looks like you did not put any effort into researching and investigating the solution. Right on the [front page of the project](https://code.google.com/p/apv/):

"Native Android PDF Viewer based on [MuPDF](http://www.mupdf.com/) library"

Comment: yes i try it but when i build "build-native.sh" it display error i m using cygwin for create .so file. in this page https://code.google.com/p/apv/wiki/Building display all information like" Running scripts/build_native.sh will then copy the files from these tarballs" but i don't know what is "tarballs", and how many files i have to put in jni folder(or it genreted by the script"build-native.sh").

Comment: After you run `build_native.sh` you should have `jni/mupdf/pdf/mupdf.h` and `jni/mupdf/fitz/fitz.h`. If you don't, then something is wrong with your cygwin. It works on mine, i just downloaded apv0.3.3 and unpacked. If you do have the files but the build is failing then ask in the apv forum (group). Before you ask questions here next time, please learn at least what tarball is. You will avoid the -1.